# Genymotion installation Error "the setup files are corrupted.Please obtain a new copy"

Tags: android, genymotion

I am a beginner in android development and need to install Genymotion. I went to its official site and downloaded setup file. I double clicked setup file. Then ı click run button for "the publisher could not be verified are you sure to run this software". After clicking run button the error message box came out with this error message:

**"the setup files are corrupted. please obtain a new copy of the program"**

I am using windows7. What should i do? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Maybe you could "obtain a new copy of the program", have you tried ? If it still doesn't work then we might try something else

Comment: I tried many times with different browser, ı checked my internet connection but i saw same error

Comment: just reinstall it as this version corrupted

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what link you went for, but try the following work:

http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.5.3/genymotion-2.5.3-vbox.exe

Comment: i tried this link but it said "the setup files are corrupted" again

Comment: i see .. the link is working 100% with me ... I think the problem would be in your system .. try this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJHrbcrnfZE) ... google your error too "the setup files are corrupted"

Answer (score 0):

Chack your system for viruses. Maybe, the setup file gets corrupted by some virus immediately after you download it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it has nothing to do with genymotion.

You might have a virus...

Try running your favorite antimalware. Good luck !